# Swapping between standard and free tiers - Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

What happens if I have an Azure website that's in the Standard tier with WebJob's on a schedule, SSL, etc. and then switch back to the free tier to save costs?

Will I be able to switch back to the Standard tier and have all of my previous configuration settings in tact?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to refer this link and check if it answers your questions. It clearly talks about upgrade or downgrade a website.
Here is the link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn167003.aspx
Let us know if it helps.
Regards,
Azam Khan

Comment: This doesn't really say anything about any limitations but doesn't make me confident that my site wouldn't get messed up when swapping...